# Recasting of 'this' workaround

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, chess

I'm trying to create a simple chess program and I've came a across little problem when implementing pawn promotion. I have an abstract class Piece and 6 classes (King, Queen, Rook, Knight, Bishop and Pawn) extending it. So when a pawn reaches the other end of the board I want him to change to let's say Queen.

Easiest would be to do something like this:

```
Public class Pawn extends Piece {
...
  @Override
  public void move(int toCol, int toRow) {
    this.col = toCol; this.row = toRow;
    if (toRow == endRow)
      this = (Queen)this
  }
}
```

Which is obviously impossible because one can simply not assign to *this*.

So i need to detect promotion and cast it from outside. But for some reasons I store the piece configuration twice. As a 2D array of Pieces but also as 2 lists of pieces of each player. Which means I need to find the pawn in the list and remove it, then add new queen with same coordinates and then assign her to the board[col][row].

I would like to know if there is a nicer way to do it. Somehow to change the class of the object from "inside".

Comment: Changing an object's class type for an object instance is not something Java allows.  Instead, you might consider removing the pawn instance and replacing it with a new Queen instance.  Or...  you could have an enum representing type and a member variable to hold it in your Piece class and switch the type that way...

Comment: Do you understand what a cast means? Casting object references does not in any way convert objects from one type to another, so you cannot use this to convert a `Pawn` object to a `Queen` object. The only thing casting does is tell the compiler that you want to temporarily disable type checking. The check will still be done, at runtime, and when it fails you'll get a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Basically, you can replace your mini passenger car with an SUV, but you can't change a mini into an SUV.

Answer (score 5):

I do not understand, what you want to accomplish. If you model after the *physical* chessgame, your pawn is *dropped* and another chess piece is used instead. So the pawn is `removed` from your gameboard and a queen is `inserted`at the pawns former position. 
[You can not simply change the class of an instance.](https://imgflip.com/i/hws4s)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you probably shouldn't be using different classes for your different pieces. This is something that seems to appear in every object-oriented book and really doesn't make sense. Especially because you're telling it to `move` externally.

I'd just write it up as one class with an enum variable `type` and just reassign that to `QUEEN` from `PAWN`.

For example, here's what it might look like.

```
public class Piece{
    public static enum ChessType{PAWN, ROOK, BISHOP, KNIGHT, QUEEN, KING;}
    private ChessType type;
    ...
    public void move(int toCol, int toRow) {
        switch(type){
            case PAWN:
            this.col = toCol; this.row = toRow;
            if (toRow == endRow)
                this = (Queen)this;
            }
            break;
            ... //Handle the rest
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make your `move` method return the moved piece. Something like

```
@Override
public Piece move(int toCol, int toRow) {
    if (toRow == endRow) {
      return new Queen(toCol, toRow);
    }
    return new Pawn(toCol, toRow);
  }
```

This way, you could make your `Piece` object immutable.